# Mapping keywords from CSV with DataFrames: why does index counter retrieve index no. 10 twice?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV table in which I am mapping words found in a PDF file to new words I want to use in a book index,

e.g.

```
WORD;TYPE;MAP TO;Chapter;Page in 2nd proof (manual spot-checks);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Battle of White Mountain;EVENT;Battle of White Mountain;MALTE;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Protectorate;EVENT;Protectorate (Commonwealth of England);MB;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Restoration;EVENT;English Restauration;#;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
wars of religion;EVENT;wars of religion;DAVID;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
war of religion;EVENT;wars of religion;DAVID;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
confessional warfare;EVENT;wars of religion;DAVID;#;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Here is a sample CSV file containing the 12 first keywords:

[CSV on GITHUB](https://github.com/MonikaBarget/DigitalHistory/blob/master/BRILL_INDEX_12lines.csv)

The script I am using to read the CSV as data frame, get the page numbers for the old keywords from the PDF file, map the old keywords to the new keywords, and write the results into a dictionary of list, it the following:

[SCRIPT on GITHUB](https://github.com/MonikaBarget/DigitalHistory/blob/master/BookINDEX_find&replaceKEYWORDS.py)

The first ten keywords are correctly mapped, and the page numbers are correctly added to the dictionaries:

```
The document has 310 pages.
TRYING TO FIND Battle of White Mountain :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 0
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 0    Battle of White Mountain
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Battle of White Mountain
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125]}
TRYING TO FIND Protectorate :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 1
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 1    Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97]}
TRYING TO FIND Restoration :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 2
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 2    English Restauration
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD English Restauration
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11]}
TRYING TO FIND Frankenburg dice game :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 3
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 3    Frankenburg Dice Game
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Frankenburg Dice Game
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134]}
TRYING TO FIND Frankenburg rebellion :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 4
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 4    Frankenburg Rebellion
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Frankenburg Rebellion
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116]}
TRYING TO FIND Glorious Revolution :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 5
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 5    Glorious Revolution
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Glorious Revolution
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285]}
TRYING TO FIND Restauração :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 6
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 6    Portuguese Restoration
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Portuguese Restoration
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218]}
TRYING TO FIND Thirty Years' War :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 7
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 7    Thirty Years' War
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Thirty Years' War
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": []}
TRYING TO FIND Peasant War :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 8
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 8    Upper Austrian Peasant War
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD Upper Austrian Peasant War
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": [], 'Upper Austrian Peasant War': [115, 124]}
TRYING TO FIND wars of religion :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 9
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 9    wars of religion
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD wars of religion
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": [], 'Upper Austrian Peasant War': [115, 124], 'wars of religion': [10, 96]}
TRYING TO FIND war of religion :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 10
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 10    wars of religion
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD wars of religion
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": [], 'Upper Austrian Peasant War': [115, 124], 'wars of religion': [10, 96, 135, 143]}
```

However, the 11th word and all the following are no longer mapped correctly as my counter delivers the index position `10` twice, which leads to a mismatch and prompts the script to write the old keywords into the dictionary according to my exception handling. This is the console output where I could trace the error:

```
TRYING TO FIND war of religion :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 10
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 10    wars of religion
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
FINAL INDEX WORD wars of religion
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": [], 'Upper Austrian Peasant War': [115, 124], 'wars of religion': [10, 96, 135, 143]}
TRYING TO FIND confessional warfare :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 10
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 11    wars of religion
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": [], 'Upper Austrian Peasant War': [115, 124], 'wars of religion': [10, 96, 135, 143], 'confessional warfare': []}
TRYING TO FIND Africa :
POSITION IN DATAFRAME: 11
WORD IN DATAFRAME: 12    Africa
Name: MAP TO, dtype: object
{'Battle of White Mountain': [125], 'Protectorate (Commonwealth of England)': [95, 97], 'English Restauration': [11], 'Frankenburg Dice Game': [115, 118, 132, 134], 'Frankenburg Rebellion': [116], 'Glorious Revolution': [181, 182, 264, 266, 267, 285], 'Portuguese Restoration': [198, 205, 218], "Thirty Years' War": [], 'Upper Austrian Peasant War': [115, 124], 'wars of religion': [10, 96, 135, 143], 'confessional warfare': [], 'Africa': [12, 13, 201, 218, 289, 299, 300, 308, 310]}
```

Why does the counter retrieve `10` twice, and how can I fix this?

Comment: How many PDFs are you using? Have you tried reducing your set of input files to the minimum set that still allows you to reproduce the problem? It's always helpful to post some input files that allow others to reproduce and debug the error.

Comment: It is one PDF file of 310 pages. The CSV file has more than 2000 rows / keywords which ought to be mapped to circa 700 index words. It is a good idea to use a CSV file with just 12 rows to test. Will upload a sample to GITHUB and edit the questions.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. I am using the number of items in my constantly updated output dictionary to get the index. Which obviously fails as soon as it start over-writing old keys. Will try and get the index from the original keyword itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to get the data frame index for each original keyword, and not an index number relative to the dictionary size:

`df_count=int(df[df["WORD"]== i].index.values) # get index number as integer`